# User.Identity different based on method call with same token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, access-token

I'm getting some behaviour I don't understand after trying ASP.NET Identity. I chose the Web API option in VS 2015 and that creates a AccountController.cs for you. I added my own controllers and got an issue with the User.Identity object. When I do a call to /api/Account/IsAuthenticated the `User.Identity` Object doesn't contain the information of the token. Method looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("IsAuthenticated")]
public bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

In my other controller, CategoryController.cs, I have a method which listens to `/Category/GetAllCategories` which looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAllCategories()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    return Json(Category.GetAllCategories(userId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now the weird part is that in GetAllCategories my User object contains the right information from the token. The way I make a request is the same for both methods. Only the url is different.

```
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST", 
        url: baseurl + "/api/Account/IsAuthenticated", 
        headers: headers})
    .done(function (data) { console.log(data); })
    .fail(function (data) { console.log("fail"); console.log(data); });
}
```

**My Question:** Why is my User.Identity in AccountController empty?

*Not really sure what information is needed for a proper answer. If you need more info, please feel free to ask.*

Comment: You're making POST request to IsAuthenticated method; while that method is marked as HttpGet only - are you sure (if you debug the method) that you indeed land there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an issue with in my `Startup.cs`. It looked like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    //ConfigureAuth(app);
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    app.UseWebApi(config);  
    ConfigureAuth(app); 
}
```

I had to move the `ConfigureAuth(app)` above the `app.UseWebApi(config)`. Still don't understand why this solved it. Can someone explain why this does make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

This causes the request to use anonymous. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. When I do that I get a 401 Unauthorized. So for some reason my Accountcontroller doesn't accept my token?